# Is it possible to automatically create a plane between two spheres when they move and reach each other?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, node-editor, geometry-nodes

Is it possible in Blender to do something like, whenever these two spheres move and reach each other, a plane automatically gets created between them?

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried the answer below and then changed the position of one of the spheres using the `Combine XYZ` but no grids got visible. Am I doing something wrong with my nodes?

[image]

Blender file:

[image]

Comment: yes, you could easily achieve this effect with geometry nodes. Also animation nodes can do that.

Comment: @Chris But could you please give an example of how it can be done using geometry nodes and animation nodes?

Comment: @Chris I updated my post. Is there something wrong with my node setup that does not work for me like your gif? You can also share your Blender file.

Comment: share your blend file and i will check it out

Comment: @Chris I updated my post.

Comment: just increase your "less than" value, then the grid will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this node tree:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]